# Installing FAAC on linux, getting errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to install FAAC on linux. I'm getting errors.

I use this to install.

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/faac/files/faac-src/faac-1.28/faac-1.28.tar.bz2/download
tar -xvjf faac-1.28.tar.bz2
cd faac-1.28
./configure
make
make install
```

Once I try to make it, I get the error

```
mpeg4ip.h:126: error: new declaration ‘char* strcasestr(const char*, const char*)’
/usr/include/string.h:369: error: ambiguates old declaration ‘const char* strcasestr(const char*, const char*)’
make[3]: *** [3gp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/faac-1.28/common/mp4v2'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/faac-1.28/common'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/faac-1.28'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I read up online and it was saying it was interfearing with something, and I had to locate a file and edit it.

How do i fix this installation so it install properly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Remove line 126 containing strcasestr from mpeg4ip.h found in the common/mp4v2 folder, as a temporary workaround. It seems it does not properly exclude its own prototype when it is already included by means of glibc's strcasestr (#define _GNU_SOURCE 1).

BTW: Isn't ffmpeg on the way to have its own AAC code such that faac/faad is no longer needed as a dependency...

Comment: Yes, however, when I install FFMPEG it doesn't show faac and faad are installed.

Comment: The file is located in commom/mp4v2.

Comment: This helped me get faac installed on an Amazon EC2 CentOS image--thanks!

Comment: sed -i.bak 's|char \\*strcasestr(const char \\*haystack, const char \\*needle);|/\\* removed so that faac compiles correctly: & \\*/|g' common/mp4v2/mpeg4ip.h

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 - kernel 3.5x to 3.8.0-32-generic

Step 1:

```
apt-get -y remove gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
apt-get -y install libfaad-dev libfaac-dev faac faad
```

Step 2:

```
cd /var/tmp

wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-bad/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23.tar.gz
tar xvfz gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23.tar.gz
cd gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23/
./autogen.sh
./configure

configure: *** Plug-ins with dependencies that will be built:
    decklink
    dvb
    faac
    faad
    fbdevsink
    gsettings
    linsys
    shm
    vcdsrc
    vp8

make

Making all in faac
make[3]: Entering directory `/var/tmp/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23/ext/faac'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23/ext/faac'

Making all in faad
make[3]: Entering directory `/var/tmp/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23/ext/faad'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23/ext/faad'

Making all in gsettings

make install
```

Step 3: verify

```
gst-inspect-0.10 faac | grep Version
  Version:      0.10.21

gst-inspect-0.10 faad | grep Version
  Version:      0.10.23
```

EDIT: deb packages

http://labkom.stikom.edu/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gst-plugins-bad0.10/